# Where to find a list of the Padovan numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am writing some code that calculates the Padovan sequence.

I want to test my code to check that the $73$rd term is correct (without using my program to calculate it, as that would defeat the purpose of the test).

Does anyone know where I can find a list of the first 100+ (the more the merrier) Padovan numbers?

Comment: It's a recursion, no?  Just generate the terms on a spreadsheet.  Usual is, I think, $a_0=1,a_1=0=a_2$ and $a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$, no?  If so, I see $a_{73}=145547525$  but maybe there are different definitions.

Comment: thanks P(0) = P(1) = P(2) = 1

Comment: with $a_0=a_1=a_2=1$ I see $a_{73}=593775046$

Comment: thanks test passed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard reference for integer sequences is the [OEIS](https://oeis.org).

A quick search shows that the Padovan numbers are sequence [A000931](https://oeis.org/A000931). NB for many sequences including this one there are varying conventions about the indexing of the sequence. (From the comments I see that OP is using convention $P(0) = P(1) = P(2) = 1$, and the entry's convention has a relative offset of $-5$ from this one.) The first entry in the $\texttt{LINKS}$ subsection of the latter link is a [list of the first $\sim 8000$ entries of the sequence](https://oeis.org/A000931/b000931.txt).

Comment: exactly what I needed many thanks

Comment: Cheers, I'm glad you found it useful.